# Riemannian Metric definition, Definition 2.1. chapter 1 Do Carmo Riemannian Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, definition

This is probably a stupid question. The book in the title defines

> Definition 2.1. A *Riemannian metric* on a differentiable manifold $M$ is a correspondence which associates to each point $p$ of $M$ an inner product $\left\langle \cdot,\cdot \right\rangle_p$ (that is symmetric, bilinear, positive definite form) on the tangent space $T_p M$, which varies differentiably in the following sense: If $x : U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to M$ is a system of coordinates around $p$, with $x(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = q \in x(U)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(q) = dx_q (0,\ldots,1,\ldots,0)$, then $\left\langle \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(q),\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(q)\right\rangle_q = g_{ij}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is a differentiable function in $U$

The first issue is the exact meaning of
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} (q) = dx_q (0,\ldots,1,\ldots, 0)
$$

In general the differential of a map is the Jacobian of the coordinate transformation. I.e. if $\varphi$ is a differentiable map between two differentiable manifolds then it's differential is a linear map between the two tangent spaces of such manifolds. This map is characterized by the jacobian matrix of the coordinate transformation.

I would assume that $d x_q$ then is simply the velocity vector at $q$, does the notation $dx_q(0,\ldots,1,\ldots 0)$ means simply the $i-th$ row or column of this matrix?

The second issue...

It is my understanding that $\left\langle \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(q),\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(q)\right\rangle_q$ is an inner product on the tangent space $T_q M$. Two generic elements $X,Y \in T_q M$ generic element of such space would be given by

$$
\begin{array}{l}
X = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i(q) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \\
Y = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i(q) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}
\end{array}
$$

However in a more simple setting (like regular surfaces) the Riemannian metric degenerates simply in the first fundamental form, however I do struggle to put the bits of the definition together to show this.

The reason of this question is that I'd like to assume I have some $X,Y \in T_p M$ how do I use the definition of Riemannian metric to compute the dot product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fellow student of a Riemannian Geometry course here.

First off, Do Carmo is a poor textbook for a first introduction. I'd recommend reading another more accessible and thorough textbook first.

The differential of a map in differential geometry (of which Riemannian Geometry is a subgeometry) is a derived map on the tangent vectors. Intuitively, you can define it as follows. Let $\gamma$ be a curve in $M$ with velocity vector $\vec{v}$ at $m$, and let $f: M \to N$ be a smooth map, then the differential of $f$ is the smooth map which maps $\vec{v}$ to the velocity vector of $f \circ \gamma$ at $f(m)$.

If the map is a diffeomorphism (charts are), the differential will map a base of the tangent space $T_m M$ to a basis of the tangent space at $T_{f(m)} N$.

So $d \mathbf{x}_q$ is a map from the tangent space of $\mathbb{R}^n$ at $x^{-1}(q)$ (which is just $\mathbb{R}^n$ again), to the tangent space of $M$ at $q$. You're mapping one of the canonical base vectors $(0, \ldots, 1, \ldots, 0)$ to a corresponding tangent vector in your manifold. As you pointed out, there is a close relation to the Jacobian; the Jacobian is a matrix, and therefore it maps vectors to vectors.

Your interpretation as an inner product is correct. I do not understand what you mean by the first fundamental form, however. Do you mean to use the standard Euclidian product defined on $\mathbb{R}^3$ to define a Riemannian metric on a regular space in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: By first fundamental form I mean essentially the bilinear form: $$\begin{pmatrix} \lVert x_u \rVert^2 & \left\langle x_u, x_v \right\rangle \\ \left\langle x_u, x_v \right\rangle & \lVert x_v \rVert^2 \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: You won't actually be able to manipulate the definition in order to prove that a Riemannian metric is equal to the first fundamental form, as that is *not true*. The definition allows leeway for a number of Riemannian metrics to be defined. The first fundamental form is only one of them. You should later see how to pullback a specific Riemannian metric (the Euclidian one) from a manifold ($\mathbb{R}^3$) to one of its submanifolds (a regular surface), in which case you'll retrieve that bilinear form.

Comment: That's not what I wanted to do, I wanted to prove in that specific setting degenerates in that. It doesn't really matter anyway as long as I grasp the concept. As I said in my question I cannot understand how to use the definition to compute the dot product of two vectors in tangent space, as I think the notation is confusing. When you talk about $dx_q$ in the canonical base, can you please expand the full expression?

Comment: Also, by the way, I'm reading specifically chapter 5 of differential geometry of curve and surfaces of the same author, since sometimes the same concepts are introduced and sometimes they're more intuitive, definition 5a is the same as the one I'm asking in my question.

Comment: At this point in the course, you shouldn't be able to calculate dot products on a regular surface. As I said, there is no specific Riemannian geometric on a given manifold.

Comment: Let $p \in M$ be a point of the Riemannian manifold. Then there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $p$ so that we can consistently define a set of $n$ tangent vectors $v_k$ which vary smoothly and form a basis for each tangent space of $U$. At every point in a Riemannian manifold, the Riemannian metric is a matrix $g_{ij}$, defined by the relation $g_{ij} = \langle v_i, v_j \rangle$. Knowing those coefficients $g_{ij}$ allows you to calculate inproducts. Note that they are dependent on the chosen $v_k$!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95292/discussion-between-user8469759-and-alexander-geldhof).

Comment: Sure, I'm available right now.

Answer (score 1):

1. Basically, do Carmo is denoting by  $x:U\to M$ a coordinate map. In my opinion, this  is somewhat confusing notation, so let's use $\phi:U\to M$ instead.  What he is saying is that if $q$ is the image of $p\in U$, i.e. $q=\phi(p)$, then by  definition $d\phi_p: T_p U=\mathbb{R}^n\to T_qM$. Then, if $e_i$ is the $i^{th}$ standard basis vector on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $1\le i \le n$, the  definition of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(q)$ is exactly 
   $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\bigg|_q=d\phi_p(e_i).$$
   So, associated to a coordinate system $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ on $M$, we get by taking the images of the  standard basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ a basis for $T_qM$, namely these $\partial_{x_i}(q)$ operators.
2. In the context of surfaces $M\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, the first fundamental form is typically defined as a bilinear form $I:T_qM\times T_qM\to T_qM$ so that with $v,w\in T_qM$, $I(v,w)=\langle v,w\rangle_M$ where $\langle v,w\rangle_M$ denotes the restriction of the dot product $\langle\:\cdot,\cdot\:\rangle_{\mathbb{R}^3}$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $M$. Classically, the matrix representation of $I$ with respect to a basis $v_q,w_q$ of $T_qM$ is 
   $$ \begin{bmatrix}
   E(q)&F(q)\\
   F(q)&G(q)
   \end{bmatrix}$$
   where (as for any symmetric bilinear form) $E(q)=\langle v_q,v_q\rangle$, $F(q)=\langle v_q,w_q\rangle=\langle w_q,v_q\rangle$, and $G(q)=\langle w_q,w_q\rangle$. So, if we were to use this bilinear form as the metric of $M\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ an embedded surface, taking $(x_1,x_2)$ as coordinates near $q\in M$, we would get associated partial derivatives $(\partial_1,\partial_2)_q$ and then in terms of these coordinates, $E(q)=\langle \partial_1(q),\partial_1(q)\rangle_q=g_{11}(q)$, 
   $$F(q)=\langle \partial_1(q),\partial_2(q)\rangle_q=\partial_2(q),\partial_1(q)\rangle_q=g_{12}(q)=g_{21}(q)$$
   and $G(q)=\langle \partial_2(q),\partial_2(q)\rangle_q=g_{22}(q)$. So, the matrix of the first fundamental form is 
   $$ 
   \begin{bmatrix}
   g_{11}(q)&g_{12}(q)\\
   g_{12}(q)&g_{22}(q)
   \end{bmatrix}$$
   in terms of our new notion of $g_{ij}$. Of course, the case of $M\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ is special, because  the choice of embedding $i:M\hookrightarrow{} \mathbb{R}^3$ endows the surface with  a metric inherited from $\mathbb{R}^3$.
3. To *compute* inner products of tangent vectors on a Riemannian manifold (or of vector fields), fix local coordinates $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ around a point $q$ of interest. Then compute the $g_{ij}(q)$. Knowing this information completely determines the quadratic form of the inner product, which is then given by a matrix $(g_{ij})$
   $$ 
   \begin{bmatrix}
   g_{11}&\cdots& g_{1n}\\
   \vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
   g_{n1}&\cdots& g_{nn}
   \end{bmatrix}. $$ 
   Now, if in terms of the tangent vectors $(\partial_1(q),\ldots, \partial_n(q))$, and $v,w\in T_qM$, 
   $$ w=
   \begin{bmatrix}
   w_1\\
   \vdots\\
   w_n
   \end{bmatrix},\:\:\:\:\:
   v=
   \begin{bmatrix}
   v_1\\
   \vdots\\
   v_n
   \end{bmatrix}.$$
   Then $\langle v,w\rangle_q=v^T(g_{ij})w$ as normal matrix multiplication.

Comment: In your first point there's a mismatch in notation I think, but I might be wrong. You say $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(q)$ but then $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\bigg|_p=d\phi_p(e_i).$$
So $p$ instead of $q$.

Comment: Thanks, edited. It's probably not the only one.

Comment: Also shouldn't it be: $$\alpha_1(p) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\bigg|_p=d\phi_p(e_i), $$ namely some coefficient multiplying the operator?

Comment: No, the coefficient is necessarily $=1$.

Comment: Why is that? Is it because of the canonical basis?

Comment: We are _defining_ it this way.

Comment: I struggle to understand what we are defining at this point. Because if $x_q$ is a coordinate system around $q$ isn't it's differential well defined already? Or are we actually defining that symbol $$ dx_q(e_i) =  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\bigg|_p = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} (q)$$?

Comment: My understanding was that since $x$ goes from a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $M$, and $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a differentiable manifold on its own under the identity map then it's differential is well defined already.

Comment: So, basically we are defining the basis $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ for $1\le i \le n$ using the differential of the coordinate map $\phi: U\to \phi(U)\subseteq M$.

Comment: I'll read more carefully through your answer. I'm sure I'll have more questions.